How to make the position property of an object wiggle only when it is moving?
I have an object with two simple position keyframes. I would like to add some randomness to the animation but only while it is moving. As soon as it stops, the wiggle should stop, too.
In After Effects I would use a wiggle(freq,amp) expression on the position property and drive the amp parameter with the object's speed divided by some amount. This works quite well with e.g. mockup cursors, that then move on a slightly squiggly path. But they will always end up on the exact position that the keyframes have been set on, because as soon as they stop, the wiggle will stop.
How would I go about this in Blender? I can't find a way to read an object's speed with a driver. Is it possible with simulation nodes? I suspect this would be the way to go, because to get the speed of an object one would have to compare the last frame's position value to the current frame's position value. Any ideas?
